# MIMEKIT MultipartSigned.Verify How can I disable Certificate Revocation list ceck?

Tags: certificate, signature, smime, mimekit, certificate-revocation

is there anyway to disable the **Certificate revocation list check** when using  *MimeKit.Cryptography.MultipartSigned.Verify* ?

The Party transmitting to me cannot seem to get their CRL distribution point correct and I would like to simply disable the check.

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.
at System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignerInfo.Verify(X509Certificate2CollectionextraStore,X509Certificate2 certificate, Boolean verifySignatureOnly)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignerInfo.CheckSignature(X509Certificate2Collection extraStore, Boolean verifySignatureOnly)
   at MimeKit.Cryptography.WindowsSecureMimeDigitalSignature.Verify(Boolean verifySignatureOnly)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MimeKit.Cryptography.WindowsSecureMimeDigitalSignature.Verify(Boolean verifySignatureOnly)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried passing `verifySignatureOnly: true` to the Verify() method?